# What is the example parameter in the OAuth 2.0 RFC

Tags: oauth2

In section 4.1.4 of the [OAuth 2.0 RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#page-26), it gives an example of an access token response:

```
   An example successful response:

     HTTP/1.1 200 OK
     Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
     Cache-Control: no-store
     Pragma: no-cache

     {
       "access_token":"2YotnFZFEjr1zCsicMWpAA",
       "token_type":"example",
       "expires_in":3600,
       "refresh_token":"tGzv3JOkF0XG5Qx2TlKWIA",
       "example_parameter":"example_value"
     }
```

What is this example_parameter? It's not defined anywhere in the RFC from what I can read.

Answer (score 1):

It is there to show that if you're writing a client, you may meet an implementation that returns additional parameters that are not mentioned in the RFC, as explained in section 8.2.

(For example, this implies that you should not use a JSON parsing framework that errors out when it meets unknown parameters).